# Unorthodox approach to checking if a string is a palindrome

Tags: c#

I'm attempting to create an unorthodox approach to working out if a string is palindrome or not. I am aware of the current .Reverse() method that you can use but this is the way that I am trying to do it:

The user will enter the string and then the program will check the first and last letters of the string. If they are the same, it will keep checking. If they are not (at the start or at any particular point) then the program will declare that it is not a palindrome. Once the program stops checking and sees that no letters are not the same, it will declare that it is a palindrome.

Here is my current code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace tasks
{ 
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a message and I will check if it     is a palindrome: ");
            string message1 = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine().ToLower());
            char[] message = message1.ToCharArray();
            int i = 0;
            int j = message.Length - 1;
        if (message[i] == message[j])
        {
            do
            {
                i++;
                j--;
                if (message[i] == message[j])
                    Console.Write("This is a palindrome");
                else if (message[i] != message[j])
                    Console.Write("This is not a palindrome");
                break;
            } while (message[i] == message[j]);
        }
        else if (message[i] != message[j])
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is not a palindrome");
        }
    }
}
```

(Sorry about the indentation).

If I was to type in 'haegah', the program would say that this is a palindrome. When it is clearly not. My question is, what is causing my program to do this and how can I fix it?

Comment: ... and what should happen when `i` becomes greater than `j`?

Comment: Hmm, that's a good point. I assumed the program would stop once it reaches the middle, but it looks like it didn't :/ . I'll try to implement this in my code and see the result.

Comment: The cycle will run once once because of `break;` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've neglected to wrap `{` and `}` around `Console.Write("This is not a palindrome"); break;`. When you do this, *only the first expression becomes conditional*. The `break;` isn't encapsulated inside of the `else` branch, and will execute unconditionally thus *terminating your loop in the first iteration*.

This explains what I think is causing one of your problems, and how you can fix it. However, there are other problems.

By incrementing&decrementing your counters before you compare the characters, you're skipping two characters (the ones at the start and end). You can perform the incrementation & decrementation simultaneously in your loop condition with a comparison like: `message[i++] == message[j--]`...

Even if you fix these, your loop *won't terminate sanely*; the two variables will overlap, and then you'll continue until one is negative and the other is out of bounds (well, technically, they're both out of bounds)... In addition to your loop executing while `message[i] == message[j]`, it should also only execute while `i < j`.

But wait, there's *another problem*! What do you suppose will happen when the string is an empty string? You need to guard against that condition *before* your loop, or use a `while (...) { ... }` loop.

Comment: Thanks a million! I'll work on each of the points you just stated and go for it!

Comment: My suggestion would actually be to work on reversing a string, since the loop you're crafting is how you'd want to go about that... Get that working, so you can better test it by observation, then tweak it to perform palindromic tests instead.

Comment: Through your suggestions, I ended up figuring out a solution! I put the Console.WriteLine(". . .") in { } and then put break; in each of the { }. Then I put i++; and j--; at the end of the while loop. It worked well. Thank you very much! (I'll mark your answer as correct just to confirm to any new visitors that this question has been answered).

Comment: Much appreciated. Too many questions end up with a "Thanks! That solved my problem!" and no tick... hehe... Welcome to the community. I look forward to next time :)